# Efficient placement of variable size rectangles within a rectangular field

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming

This seems to me like it may be a version of the knapsack problem: I have a list of rectangles of varying sizes that I want to place within a field without overlapping or grouping similar sizes.

Would it be correct to start looking in the knapsack direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear for me. **randomly**, **non overlapping** and **list**. Take two out of three.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that doesn't make sense. What I meant by random is to avoid having similarly sized ones placed together.

Comment: Still not clear. To design an algorithm (or to chose one) you need some precision. What is _"similarly sized"_ and _"placed together"_?. And remember to answer comments with @user or the poster is not notified :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, thats some the same kind of problem like the knapsack-problem - it's more difficult because you have to take care of 2 dimensions, not just one - but with looking for the knapsack-problem, you're on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

It is at least as hard as knapsack because it a knapsack problem can be solved using it by making the field and rectangles fixed width (a width smaller than the smallest length of any rectangle).